# How to create a action method to make a picker view appear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, uipickerview

I have a view controller where I have a textview which is the keyboard is the first responder and coming up when this view controller is loaded.

I added an accessory view (with a button) to the textview and in the view did load made the `self.myTextView.inputAccessoryView = self.accessoryView;` , so now when the keyboard comes up it have my accessory view with a button on it....oh and i dragged the accessory view to the scene so it won't be in the view hierarchy.

Now I want to add a picker view where I can choose a countdown time like "1 hour", "2 hours" etc.

How can I use this button on my accessory vice to fire up the picker view?

I created an action method from the button to the view controller `setTimerWasPressed` so I guess the code goes here, but what should I do to make the picker view come up instead of the keyboard when I click on the setTimerWasPressed method..?

thanks

Comment: You put the picker as a inmputView in order to appear instead of the keyboard:  [textView setInputView:picker];

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the problem, but here is my sample code:

```
@implementation CustomKeyboard
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
    CGRect selfFrame = self.frame;
    CGFloat buttonSize = 50;
    self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((selfFrame.size.width - buttonSize)/2, (selfFrame.size.height - buttonSize)/2, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
    self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    self.datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self addSubview:self.button];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(showDataPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
- (void)showDataPicker:(id)sender {
    [self insertSubview:self.datePicker atIndex:self.subviews.count];
}
@end
```

Hope it helps you.